# Avoid Data Cache after generating report with embedded Pentaho Report Designer Classic Engine

Tags: java, caching, reporting, pentaho

I'm using Vaadin 6.8 and pentaho classic engine 5.0.1 embedded to my application. I've successfully generated the reports in the formats required and with parameters established. The issue comes when I noticed that after generating the report, there is something like a **data-cache** that doesn't allow me to get updated data from the datasource (MySQL jdbc in report definition). The report generator is generating new files, but the data is not updated because of this cache, it means that, different files are generated with the same data content, even when I update it directly in the database. I'm forced to close my vaadin application and generate the reports again to get the update on the report data, but I cannot close the user session every time to get it working as requirement.

After many days I've found this, where it explains that disabling **data-cache** is enough to avoid that problem:

http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?82765-Engine-3-8-disable-data-caching

I've tried to set that **config-key** via my java classes, but I don't know how to set that key, so I decided to search more about this, and in the next link, says that is possible but using a BI-server.:

http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fperformance_tuning_guide%2Ftopic_reporting_caching.html

My application runs alone in a server, and I can't use the BI-server as I only need the report generator, that's the purpose of using embedded report generator. How can I set that config-key via Java classes or in a way that I can handle all in my Java application? or how can I avoid data-cache on report generation with classic engine?

Comment: At the moment, got a temporal solution, sending a random number as dummy parameter for the report, so, it forces the reporting engine to fetch the data again, because the new parameter is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I've found to avoid data-cache without a global **config-key** is to define data-cache = false at Pentaho 's Report Designer Master Report attributes while editing a report.